# Django Social Auth Linkedin Rest API Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

I'm using Django Social Auth with Linkedin OAuth2 backend and keep getting a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error when trying to authenticate with my Linkedin account.

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "UE6GBQYK4T",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1515645281366
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using social-auth-core 1.5 instead of 1.6 solved the issue for me.

There was a bug introduced in 1.6, which is discussed here https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/173